# Android Studio: Need to know which folders/files to backup

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to take backup of Android project. But the entire folder structure size is very big (goes upto few hundreds of MBs) for periodical backups. Basically I want to take backup of only source and configuration files (so that I should be able to build project successfully just with backup). I don't care generated and intermediate files.

But when I've look at folder structure, it looks too confusing and cannot make which folders/files I should backup and which should discard (Yes, I can find out my own written source files, but which are config and other files needed by Android Studio?)

[image]

Can someone please guide?

Thanks!

Comment: The app folder is enough. Also if you see a build folder inside your `app` folder delete it, it is heavy and you can reproduce it later.

Comment: Ok so build, gradle, .gradle, idea etc are studio generated and no need to backup? Sure, I'll try this one. Many thanks!

Comment: You can keep the rest, just get rid that build folder. Its heavy.

Comment: @Atul, See my suggestions below https://stackoverflow.com/a/52511073/8034839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You backup whatever is important. For each project or library, do backup these:

1. `src` folder (contains source code, resource files)
2. `build.gradle` file (contains info about dependencies, libs)

Do not need to backup:

1. `build` folder
2. `gen` folder
3. `.gradle` folder

Note: `Clean Project` sometimes does not remove generated files.

Comment: And everything you mentioned is from app folder right?

Comment: more accuracies: in the app/src folder only the "main" folder and the app/buil.gradle with this you get the necesary files to bakcup but the restore task you must create a new project with the same name and overwite the src/main and app/buil.gradle

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it is very simple in the android studio. Only you have to do is just

**File ->Export to Zip File**
This will create a zip file of your project. This Zip file will only contain the files that are necessary, to import the project back into Android studio again.

**Edit:** ***From the new Android Studio Version Export to Zip flow changed(My Version: Android studio 4.1, Running in Mac Os Catalina).
Now it is File->Manage IDE Settings ->Export to Zip FIle.***

Answer (score 1):

> Basically I want to take backup of only source and configuration files
>   (so that I should be able to build project successfully just with
>   backup). I don't care generated and intermediate files.

For a reproducible backup, only backing up the the `src` and `build.gradle` is not sufficient. Because if you want to have a **consistent** build for your project, you need to have the same source code and configurations, for example, the top level `build.gradle` as well as the app level `build.gradle`. So, I would like to recommend below steps for an **Android Studio** project to have a really clean status before doing backup.

1. Close your android studio, this is to avoid the IDE automatically trigger the build to generate the intermediate files.
2. Open command line and `cd` to your project root directory, i.e. `<path>/FusedLocationAPISample` for your case.
3. Run `$ rm -rf .gradle .idea build app/build` on **linux** or **macOS**, or run `rd /s /q .gradle .idea build app/build` on **Windows**. This command is to delete the **gradle** and **Intellj** intermediate files as well as the **build** intermediate files.
4. All the other files, e.g. the `gradle-wrapper.properties`, `settings.gradle`, `gradle.properties`, etc, **HAVE TO** be kept there if you want to reproduce a consistent build next time. This is because the project setting and gradle version and properties are important for a consistent build.

Then the last step is to use your preferred way to back up your project, e.g. using ZIP and backup to a spared drive.

But, I would like to suggest using Github, Bitbucket (or some other SCM tools) to manage your code As those SCM tools are much intelligent and easier to use, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually need to make copies of my android studio projects. The size of the copy is mostly affected by generated files which aren't vital for a successful build of the project copy, but if not present you need to wait for them to be generated again.

Directories I ignore when copying:

- root

  - **.gradle**
  - **.idea**
  - **build**
  - app (or any other module)

    - **build**

Also you may have some debug/release APK files that you don't want to keep in the copy.

Windows [xcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) can make your life easier due to its **exclude** option (for APK files add '.apk'). Furthermore you may like to check out this windows tool as you can reuse your exclude configurations: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xcopygui

Answer (score -1):

Use *Build* -> *Clean Project* to clean it and remove all generated files.
Then you have the list of files to backup.

Comment: With this approach next time when I build, it takes huge lot of time to regenerate all those deleted files. As a workaround I have to take another copy of originals and restore after backup.

Comment: It would take that one time.  Then you'd save those, and in the future only need to add new resources and source files.  And honestly if you aren't willing to spend that time to do it yourself, why should we spend our time trying to help?

Comment: `It would take that one time` still not convincing approach you see in the course of time we would not only change sources but also add remove sources n resources and also config (e.g. version number change)

Comment: Clean does not leave you with only the files you need to backup, there is still a ton of junk there. After doing a clean and tar-ing up the files for 2 projects, the tar files are 47 meg and 92 meg - for small projects! My actual files are probably a couple meg for both.

Comment: This is bad practice and shouldn't be encouraged. The concept of generated files exists for a reason.